# Hibernate IN Clause with multiple columns

Tags: hibernate

Need to know how to construct a Hibernate Query which fetches results matching an `IN` clause containing multiple column values.

e.g.,

```
Query query=session.createQuery( "from entity e where (e.abc, e.xyz) in (:list)" );
query.setParameterList( "list", list );
```

Here `list` would be a 2D array that could contain basic wrapper objects for primitive types e.g., `Integer`, `String` etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Putting down here how I implemented this. Basically we need to make a Hibernate Component (read @Embeddable object) out of the set of columns we need to query on and embed it in the main Entity.

The group of columns can be combined as below:

```
@Embeddable
public class CompositeColumns{
  private String col1;
  private String col2;

  //Empty constructor is required by Hibernate for instantiation
  public CompositeColumns(){
  }

  public CompositeColumns(String col1, String col2){
            this.col1 = col1;
            this.col2 = col2;
      }

  @Column(name="COL1")
  public String getCol1(){
  }
  ...
  ... 
  //Rest of getters and setters
}
```

---

Embed the above in your main entity class as below:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity{
 @Id
 private Integer id;
 private String col3;
 private String col4
 @Embedded
 private CompositeColumns pairedCol1Col2;
 ...
 ...
 //Getters Setters

}
```

---

The query would then look as below:

```
List<CompositeColumns> cols = //get a list of CompositeColumns type

Query query=session.createQuery( "from MyEntity where pairedCol1Col2 in (:list)" );
query.setParameterList( "list", list );
```

This does the job.

*Note: I ran this on an Oracle database*

Comment: Tried this on MySQL and it works. Only thing to remember is to add `updateable = false, insertable = false` on the `@Embeddable`'s `@Column`s if you plan on retaining the original columns in the entity for CRUD operations.

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking here is known as the tuple syntax. It is supported by Hibernate but unfortunately many databases do no support it ...

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-tuple

Comment: Could you show the syntax for the declared list in this case?

Answer (score -1):

Entity class - create the multiple searchable columns in @Embeddable class as described below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="channels_store_images")
@Data
public class ChannelsStoreImages {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name="id")
  private Integer id;

  @Embedded
  private CompositeColumns compositeColumns;

  @Embeddable
  @Data
  @AllArgsConstructor
  public static class CompositeColumns {
    @Column(name="partner_id")
    private String partnerId;
    @Column(name="entity_type")
    private String entityType;
    public CompositeColumns(){
    }
  }
}
```

Then make object of @Embeddable class and and hit the query as described below

```
public List<ChannelsStoreImages> getChannelsStoreImagesByPartnerIdAndType(List<ChannelsStoreImages.CompositeColumns> shopIdAndType) { 
  Query dbQuery =  masterEntityManager.createQuery("From ChannelsStoreImages 
               where compositeColumns IN (:query)",ChannelsStoreImages.class);
  dbQuery.setParameter("query",shopIdAndType);
  List<ChannelsStoreImages> channelsStoreImagesList = dbQuery.getResultList();
  return channelsStoreImagesList;
}
```