# Multiple column IN clause spring data jpa

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to have multiple columns in `IN` clause?

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select * from table where (column1, column2) in (:column1, :column2)")
List<Table> findByColumn1Column2In(@Param("column1") List<BigDecimal> column1, @Param("column2") List<BigDecimal> column2);`
```

Expecting a query like this:

```
select * from table where (column1, column2) in ((1,2), (3,4), (5,6))
```

Comment: You can do it by @Embeddable annotation [hibernate-in-clause-with-multiple-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897082/hibernate-in-clause-with-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 7):

Since [JPA doesn't support multi-columns `IN` clauses](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1278) I overcome this by using SQL `CONCAT` function on the DB values, and of course, on the supplied range values, as follows:

first, create the range we looking for:

```
List<String> columns;
for (i=0, i<column1.size(), i++){
    columns.add(column1.get(i) + '-' + column2.get(i));
}
```

Modify the query:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true,
       value = "select * from table where CONCAT(column1, '-', column2) in (:columns)")
List<Table> findByColumn1Column2In(@Param("columns") List<String> columns);
```

And there you nail that :-)

Comment: this won't use indexes

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible to have multiple **"In"** clause in a method.

Using spring data jpa and spring boot we can achieve this as below:

For your case you can just write the below method in your repository and it would work fine.

```
List<Table> findByColumn1InAndColumn2In(List<BigDecimal> column1,List<BigDecimal> column2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple column with `IN` clause in not yet supported by `Spring data`. You can use `@Query` annotation for custom query as below:

> @Query( "select o from MyObject o where id in :ids" ) 
>   List findByIds(@Param("ids") List inventoryIdList);