# How to filter entities with composite PK by a list of said PK using HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

Consider:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @EmbeddedId
    private FooPK pk;

    public FooPK getPk() { return pk; }
    public void setPk(FooPK pk) { this.pk = pk; }
}
```

and

```
@Embeddable
public class FooPK {
    @Column(name="ID_A")
    private Long idA;

    @Column(name="ID_B")
    private Long idB;

    public Long getIdA() { return idA; }
    public void setIdA(Long idA) { this.idA = idA; }

    public Long getIdB() { return idB; }
    public void setIdB(Long idB) { this.idB = idB; }
}
```

I have a `List<FooPK>` that I'm trying to use as a filter in HQL:

```sql
-- Just an example of what I'm trying to do.
SELECT foo FROM Foo foo
WHERE foo.pk IN (:pkList)
```

This doesn't work, because `pk` is not a single value. I'm simply trying to list all of the entities that I have the pks from.

I **can** break the list and do something like this:

```sql
-- Ugly
SELECT foo FROM Foo foo
WHERE (
       (foo.pk.idA = :idA1 AND foo.pk.idB = :idB1)
    OR (foo.pk.idA = :idA2 AND foo.pk.idB = :idB2)
    OR (foo.pk.idA = :idA3 AND foo.pk.idB = :idB3)
    -- ...
)
```

But I'm sure you can see how ugly and unscalable this is.

I'm using Java 6/JPA 1/Hibernate 3

For what it's worth, I'm using Oracle, and I'm expecting the SQL generated to be something like:

```sql
-- This works fine in my database, assuming the schema contains the refered table and columns.
SELECT foo.ID_A, foo.ID_B
FROM Foo foo
WHERE (foo.ID_A, foo.ID_B) in ((?,?), (?,?), (?, ?))
```

Comment: Did you try without the parentheses around the named parameter, as I suggested in my answer?

Comment: Which RDBMS (e.g. MySQL, Oracle etc.) are you using?

Comment: @SteveChambers I'm using Oracle (check my edit). Also, unfortunately, I have no control over the database.

Comment: *For what it's worth, I'm using Oracle, and I'm expecting the SQL generated to be something like....* So what does the generated SQL look like?  *Of course, this doesn't work, because pk is not a single value*. How do you know? Is it mentioned somewhere explicitly that this is not supported? Also, what do you mean  by 'not working'? Returns the wrong results? Throws an error?

Comment: @AlanHay If I try to use the query like this, Hibernate throws a QueryException. There's no generated SQL. If you read the question again, you'll see that this HQL is just an example of what I'm trying to do, not an actual implementation. For your second question: I don't know. Maybe that "Of course" gave you the wrong impression. I've edited it out.

Comment: @CássioRenan It looks like [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897082#26416368) (or something very similar to it) may help you.

Comment: @SteveChambers doesn't work for me. As many of the answers also suggest this should be working, I'm beginning to think my Hibernate version is simply too old. Right now, I'm trying to find a workaround. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can use the [Criteria](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html) API  to replace your `hql`.

```
// your list of FooPks
List<FooPk> pkList = ....

//Create a criteria over an entity
Criteria  criteria = session.createCriteria(Foo.class);
// add a restriction
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("pk", pkList));
// Execute query and get result.
List<Foo> foos = criteria.list();
```

Comment: Good answer. Unfortunately, I'm almost sure I'm restricted to hql only(I'll have to double-check this, tough). Sorry for not expliciting this in my question.

Comment: I ended up doing a workaround. Since this is the only answer that would actually work - despite not being hql - in my environment, I'm accepting it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for MySQL:

1. Create a `javax.persistence.NamedQuery` for the `@Entity`

   ```
   @NamedQuery(name = "select", query = "SELECT foo FROM Foo foo WHERE foo.pk IN :pks")
   ```
2. Select via

   ```
   final TypedQuery<Foo> typedQuery = this.entityManager.createNamedQuery("select", Foo.class);
   final FooPK fooPk = new FooPK(...); // Create example FooPK
   typedQuery.setParameter("pks", Arrays.asList(fooPk, fooPk));

   return typedQuery.getResultList();
   ```

The resulting SQL:

```
select ... from ... where foo0_.idA=? and foo0_.idB=? or foo0_.idA=? and foo0_.idB=?
```

(Note the two checks for each `idA` and `idB`)