# HQL SELECT WHERE complex_expr IN ()

Tags: sql, oracle, hql

I'm trying to transform this query from Oracle SQL to HQL:

```
select * from TABLE t where (t.col1, t.col2) in (('a','a'),('b','b'));
```

It runs as expected in SQL developer.

When I transform this in HQL verbatim, it also works fine:

```
String queryString =
        "select t from Table t where (t.col1, t.col2) in (('a','a'),('b','b'))";
Query q = em.createQuery(queryString);
q.getResultList()
```

I run into problems when I try to supply IN expression as list:

```
List<String> keyList = ......
String queryString =
        "select t from Table t where (t.col1, t.col2) in (:list)";
Query q = em.createQuery(queryString);
q.setParameter("list", keyList);
```

I have problems with figuring out correct format for keyList.
Following combinations all throw "*ORA-00920: invalid relational operator*":

```
List<String> testList = Arrays.asList("('a','a')");
List<String> testList = Arrays.asList("a", "a");
List<String> testList = Arrays.asList("'a','a'");
```

Am I trying the impossible? What would be the correct way of setting a list of parameters in my case?

Comment: how many elements do you have in keylist?

Comment: I have reduced it to 2 to make sure I'm not hitting some limit.

Comment: I can't help you in a *smart* way, but - if possible and if it makes sense, you could store values (you use in the IN list) into a table, and then - instead of the IN list - you'd use a subquery which selects from that table. (Just saw your comment: in Oracle, IN list is restricted to 1000 elements, so you're quite far from that :))

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897082/hibernate-in-clause-with-multiple-columns. Seems like the same issue.

Comment: You are right, that is exactly the issue that I have. Thank you for pointing that out.