# Spring Data JPA @Query with spel in a IN query List of Object

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql

```
@Query("FROM GroupUserItemFGA fga WHERE (fga.identity.itemCode,fga.identity.dataAccessLevel) IN (:#{#fgaCombination.itemCode},:#{#fgaCombination.dataAccessLevel})")
    public List<GroupUserItemFGA> findFgaBasedFga(@Param("fgaCombination") List<Dto> fgaCombination);
```

Dto has both variable as string and public with getters and setters method.

Error:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'itemCode' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.ArrayList' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

I had tried with array also..

In-stand of List if i use just Dto then it's working.

Comment: fgaCombination has list of itemcodes?

Comment: Both fields itemCode and dataAccessLevel..

Comment: You need to have a list of `itemCodes` and a list of `dataAccessLevel`. Currently you only have a list of `Dto`. Actually your error tells you, that the `List<Dto>` has no field with the name `itemCode` which is correct, as `Dto` has it. To fix it, transform the list of `Dto` into 2 separate lists

Comment: but i want my query to be like this.. where (a, b) in values((x1, y1), (x2, y2)...). So it's not separate

Comment: Refer this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897082/hibernate-in-clause-with-multiple-columns