# Use "()" in Spring data.repository @query annotation

Tags: java, spring, repository

I have sql query:

```
SELECT file From file JOIN metadata m on file.id = m.file_id where (m.key, m.value) in (('Alex', 'redis'), ('Evgeniy','123'))
```

How do I write @Query annotation for Spring data.repository interface?

I tried like so, but it doesn't work.

```
public interface FileRepository extends CrudRepository<FileEntity, UUID> {
    @Query("SELECT f FROM FileEntity f JOIN MetadataEntity m on f.id = m.file_id WHERE (m.key, m.value) in :metadataKeyValue")
    List<FileEntity> findAllByMetadataContains(@Param(":metadataKeyValue") Map<String,String> metadataKeyValue);
}
```

and

```
public interface FileRepository extends CrudRepository<FileEntity, UUID> {
    @Query(
             "SELECT f FROM FileEntity f JOIN f.metadata m WHERE (m.key, m.value) IN :metadataKeyValue"
    )
    List<FileEntity> findAllByMetadataContains(@Param("metadataKeyValue") Map<String,String> metadataKeyValue);
}
```

and like so either

```
@Query(
            value = "SELECT f FROM FileEntity f JOIN f.metadata m WHERE (m.key, m.value) IN (:metadataKeyValue)"
    )
    List<FileEntity> findAllByMetadataContains(@Param("metadataKeyValues") Map<String,String> metadataKeyValue);
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `nativeQuery=true` in `@Query` ?

Comment: Yes. I got exception:  `could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet `

Comment: Use SELECT f.* instead of SELECT f

Comment: Nope, I've got: `identifier expected, got '*'`

Comment: Good example with @Embeddable solution
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897082/hibernate-in-clause-with-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 0):

It should be replaced as  `:metadataKeyValue` to `metadataKeyValue`
and `IN (:metadataKeyValue)`

```
public interface FileRepository extends CrudRepository<FileEntity, UUID> {
    @Query("SELECT f FROM FileEntity f JOIN MetadataEntity m on f.id = m.file_id WHERE (m.key, m.value) IN (:metadataKeyValue)")
    List<FileEntity> findAllByMetadataContains(@Param("metadataKeyValue") Map<String,String> metadataKeyValue);
}
```

Comment: You are right, but the main problem in sql expression.

Comment: make sure to use something like , I have added  ,